# How to add vue-awesome icons in nuxt app?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, nuxt.js

I'm wanted to add `font-awesome` in my `universal NuxtJs` app. so i used the `vue-awesome` package for that.

**Now after istalling the package i got this error:**

```
Unexpected identifier
```

After reading from nuxt repo on github ([nuxt repo 1](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/174), [nuxt repo 2](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/438)), i realised that the issue comes when rendering it on the server. **SSR**.

**So for dev sake i silenced it with :**

*in nuxt.config.js*

`plugins: [{ src: '~plugins/vue-awesome', ssr: false },]`

**After developing, i had to face it, and i got stuck at this error :**

[**"Unexpected token <"**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFpAE.png)

**here is the code :**

*~/plugins/vue-awesome*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon.vue';
import './icons.js';

Vue.component('icon', Icon);
```

~/plugins/icons.js

```
import 'vue-awesome/icons/sign-in-alt'
import 'vue-awesome/icons/shopping-basket'
...
```

nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  build: {

    extend(config, ctx) {
        if (ctx.isClient) {
          config.module.rules.push({
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
          })
        } else {
          config.externals = [ nodeExternals({
            whitelist: ['vue-awesome']
          })]
        }
    }
  },

  plugins: ['~plugins/vue-awesome.js']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Finanlly fixed it](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/manniL/nuxt-vue-awesome-example/tree/master/)

*nuxt.config.js*

```
  plugins: [
    '~plugins/vue-awesome',
  ],

  build: {
    transpile: [/vue-awesome/]
  },
```